# Python - read everything after second or third last dot

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to get the below output from the input.

```
Input1: firstname.middlename.lastname.city.state
Expected output: city.state

Input2: firstname.middlename.lastname.city.state.
Expected output: city.state
```

This is the expression i have that works when the Input does not have . at the end:

```
'firstname.middlename.lastname.city.state'['firstname.middlename.lastname.city.state'[:'firstname.middlename.lastname.city.state'.rfind(".")].rfind(".")+1:]
```

How do i modify this expression so that `Input2` has the same output as `Input1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
input_ = 'firstname.middlename.lastname.city.state.'
x = [a for a in input_.split('.') if a]

print('.'.join(x[-2:])) # prints city.state
```

Works with both input.

Answer (score 3):

Split string based on regex

```
import re
input_string = "firstname.middlename.lastname.city.state."
".".join(re.findall(r'[^.]+', input_string)[-2:])
```

Answer (score 2):

Check whether your string ends with a dot using .endswith() then remove the last dot, eg.

```
str =  "firstname.middlename.lastname.city.state."
if str.endswith('.'):
   str = str[:-1]
```

This will remove the last . and follow your current method.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary that returns the correct slice object depending on whether the string ends in a dot.

```
>>> 
>>> s = 'firstname.middlename.lastname.city.state.'
>>> d = 'firstname.middlename.lastname.city.state'
>>> c_s = {True:slice(-3, -1), False:slice(-2, None, None)}
>>> s.split('.')[c_s[s.endswith('.')]]
['city', 'state']
>>> d.split('.')[c_s[d.endswith('.')]]
['city', 'state']
>>>
```

---

Or write a function:

```
>>> def city_state(s):
    return s.split('.')[-3:-1] if s.endswith('.') else s.split('.')[-2:]

>>> city_state(s)
['city', 'state']
>>> city_state(d)
['city', 'state']
>>>
```